# Java replace method not working for ©

Tags: java, replace

In my java program, I want to replace the © sign in a string with a space. I used replace method but it seems to not working. What would be the solution?

```
String text = "ABC©";

text.replace("©", " ");

System.out.println(text);
```

Output : ABC©

Expected output : ABC

Comment: Don't edit your question with the content of the answer, it invalidates them.

Answer (score 4):

`String` is immutable. Try

```
text = text.replace("©", "");
```

You can also see it in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: I missed it in the sample code. I modified the code.

Comment: @ANJ Please note I replaced '" "` with `""`. It's working for me.